# Referencias bibliográficas en Latex

Tags: latex, lyx

Estoy tratando de crear un documento en LyX y tengo un problema con las citas y la bibliografía.
El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\setlength{\parindent}{0 pt} %para la sangría
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %para que el programa lea las tildes
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[usenames]{color} %para resaltar palabras. Usar \textcolor{YellowGreen}{Texto a resaltar}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\hyphenation{neo-or-to-do-xia bio-ae-ro-sol} 

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>}}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\string"C:/Users/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/My Collection.bib\string"}
\begin{document}
Hola, estoy tratando de establecer citas.\parencite*{Fort2020,Fort2020a}

Por el momento tengo problemas, as usual. \parencite{OrganizacionMundialdelaSalud2020}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Las primeras dos citas corresponden a los mismos autores, y en el documento aparece así:

**Hola, estoy tratando de establecer citas.(Fort y col. 2020b; Fort y col. 2020a)
Por el momento tengo problemas, as usual. (Organización Mundial de la Salud
2020)**

Quisiera saber si hay forma de que aparezca en orden; es decir: **(Fort y col. 2020a; Fort y col. 2020b)**, o en todo caso **(Fort y col. 2020; Fort y col. 2020a)**. (Por cierto, ¿por qué aparece "y col." y no "et al."?)

Luego, en la bibliografía el resultado es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay manera de que aparezca como

- **Fort, Ricardo y col. (2020a). Potenciales...**
- **Fort, Ricardo y col.(2020b). Zonas...** (es decir, que no solo haya un guión al inicio de esta línea).